# Can I add another subnet configuration to an existing VPC using AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm trying to add a private, isolated subnet to my existing VPC using the CDK. Here are the old and new configurations.

OLD

```
Vpc = new Vpc(this, "vpc", new VpcProps
{
    Cidr = "172.0.3.0/24",
    DefaultInstanceTenancy = DefaultInstanceTenancy.DEFAULT,
    EnableDnsHostnames = true,
    EnableDnsSupport = true,
    NatGateways = 1,
    MaxAzs = 2,
    SubnetConfiguration = new ISubnetConfiguration[]
    {
        new SubnetConfiguration{ SubnetType = SubnetType.PUBLIC, CidrMask = 26, Name = "public-" },
        new SubnetConfiguration{ SubnetType = SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS, CidrMask = 26, Name = "private-" }
    }
});
```

NEW

```
Vpc = new Vpc(this, "vpc", new VpcProps
{
    Cidr = "172.0.3.0/24",
    DefaultInstanceTenancy = DefaultInstanceTenancy.DEFAULT,
    EnableDnsHostnames = true,
    EnableDnsSupport = true,
    NatGateways = 1,
    MaxAzs = 2,
    SubnetConfiguration = new ISubnetConfiguration[]
    {
        new SubnetConfiguration{ SubnetType = SubnetType.PUBLIC, CidrMask = 26, Name = "public-" },
        new SubnetConfiguration{ SubnetType = SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS, CidrMask = 26, Name = "private-" },
        new SubnetConfiguration{ SubnetType = SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED, CidrMask = 26, Name = "isolated" }
    }
});
```

However, when I make this change and then run the `cdk diff` command I get an error that isn't telling me what's going on, I think there is a bug in the AWS CDK tool, because it looks like it's failing when trying to deserialize the error message for display.

```
Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "Error" to type 'Amazon.JSII.JsonModel.Api.Response.ErrorResponseName'. Path 'name'.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'Error' was not found.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.EnumUtils.ParseEnum(Type enumType, NamingStrategy namingStrategy, String value, Boolean disallowNumber)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject[T]()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.TryDeserialize[TResponse](String responseJson)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.ReceiveResponse[TResponse]()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.Send[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest requestObject)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.Create(CreateRequest request)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.Create(String fullyQualifiedName, Object[] arguments, Override[] overrides, String[] interfaces)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Constructs.Construct..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Amazon.CDK.Resource..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2.Vpc..ctor(Construct scope, String id, IVpcProps props)
```

I'm not sure how I can find out what the cause of my error is, but if I remove that new subnet configuration the error goes away so I know it's related. Does someone know what the underlying error might be here or how I can get the CDK to tell me the real error?

BTW, I have noticed that the Cidr is a /24 whereas my CidrMask is set to 26 but I thought I wouldn't change this yet since that configuration is what is already working and active in the environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out what the problem was and it had everything to do with how rusty I am with configuring subnets. Essentially, my address range wasn't big enough to contain another subnet. I never got a legitimate error from the CDK but after researching subnet address ranges and fixing mine to support enough hosts for my subnets my problem went away. Here's the new, working configuration.

```
Vpc = new Vpc(this, "copilot-vpc", new VpcProps
{
    Cidr = "172.0.3.0/16",
    DefaultInstanceTenancy = DefaultInstanceTenancy.DEFAULT,
    EnableDnsHostnames = true,
    EnableDnsSupport = true,
    NatGateways = 1,
    MaxAzs = 2,
    SubnetConfiguration = new ISubnetConfiguration[]
    {
        new SubnetConfiguration{ SubnetType = SubnetType.PUBLIC, CidrMask = 24, Name = "public-" },
        new SubnetConfiguration{ SubnetType = SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS, CidrMask = 24, Name = "private-" },
        new SubnetConfiguration{ SubnetType = SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED, CidrMask = 24, Name = "isolated" }
    }
});
```